# Google app script : how to upload a file an FTP

Tags: google-apps-script, ftp, sftp

I am using a script to export google spreadsheet in CSV and create the file in the same folder with this code (thanks to Tanaike) :

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next();
```

Is it possible at the same time to upload the created file (CSV) in an FTP (or SFTP) server?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `Is it possible at the same time to upload the created file (CSV) in an FTP (or SFTP) server`? What FTP server? Apps Script only supports HTTP requests so you can't use FTP to transfer files anywhere.

Comment: Thank you Rafa for your answer. I mean that when my CSV file is created from my google spreadsheet with my app script, I want this csv file uploaded to an FTP server. I was thinking to do it with the script. But has you say, if Apps Script only supports HTTP, I will not be able to do so.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this isn't possible to do with Apps Script. I've added this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

> Is it possible at the same time to upload the created file (CSV) in an FTP (or SFTP) server?

*Unfortunately, this is not possible. Google Apps Script only supports HTTP requests<sup>[[1]](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)</sup>.*

#### Feature Request:

If you really want this to be added to Apps Script however, you can head over to Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and make a Feature Request with all the information about it.

#### References:

1. [Class UrlFetchApp | Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)